# Adding a Row with ComboBox to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

What i am trying to do is, I get data from a Database. The Columns will be always different so it has to be set dynamically.
What i want to add is add a Row between the Header and the first Row another Row filled with `Comboboxes`

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU38d.png)

What I tried

```
   public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Type { get; set; }
        public List<string> ComboItems { get; set;  }

        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

Depending on Type if `true` or `false` i changed the `CellTemplate` with `DataTrigger`

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=.}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path = Type}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ComboItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path= SelectedItem}"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path = Type}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path = Text}"></TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
```

with Autogenerating Columns on

```
   private void DataTableGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTemplate dt = null;

                dt = (DataTemplate)Resources["Template"];

            DataGridTemplateColumn c = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dt,
                Header = e.Column.Header,
                HeaderTemplate = e.Column.HeaderTemplate,
                HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
                SortMemberPath = e.PropertyName ,

            };
            e.Column = c;
        }
```

This somewhat works but my problem is how do I create the `ItemSource`.
It doesn't work with `DataTable` because I didn't manage to bind the Object to a DataCell

For testing purpose I tried something like this

```
    List<Value> valuelist = new List<Value>();
            List<Value> valuelist1 = new List<Value>();
            List<List<Value>> values = new List<List<Value>>();
            Value value = new Value();
            value.Type = true;
            value.ComboItems= CFGObjects;
            value.SelectedItem = "CFG01";
            value.Text = "Sample";
            Value value1 = new Value();
            value1.Type = false;
            value1.ComboItems = CFGObjects;
            value1.SelectedItem = "CFG02";
            value1.Text = "Sample1";

            Value value2 = new Value();
            value2.Type = false;
            value2.ComboItems = CFGObjects;
            value2.SelectedItem = "CFG02";
            value2.Text = "Sample2";
            valuelist.Add(value);
            valuelist.Add(value1);
            valuelist.Add(value2);
            valuelist1.Add(value1);
            valuelist1.Add(value1);
            valuelist1.Add(value1);
            values.Add(valuelist);
            values.Add(valuelist1);
            DataTableGrid.ItemsSource= values;
```

but the DataContext for every Cell is the same since the DataContext comes from the Row and i dont know how to change it.

Another thing i tried is creating a Converter.
I see the DataContext with the 3 Lists but I didn't know how to assign the List to a specific cell.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You may use DataTemplateSelector

Comment: the problem is not the template but its how do I bind my Value Objects into a Cell